# Get updated time of a particular row values in java

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file. I want to add a column of Last updated in csv file i.e.
Name Last Updated
A        2:30
B        3:30
C        5:00
I'm not able to figure out how can i get the time when a row was last updated.
Any kind of help regarding this would be much appreciated.
Thanks